# How do i make graph for shortest path problems?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I have an assignment about shortest path problem. I use Floyd-warshall algorithm for my assignment. I was told that i have to make a graph first. Is there any specific way or specific application to make graph ?
Thank you

Comment: I strongly suggest you create your own graph code and avoid using a library from someone else especially if you have not yet created a graph yourself ... that is if you really want to learn how to solve problems ... when creating your graph keep in mind the fundamental question of whether or not you need just a linked list ( to enable traversal in one direction )  or a doubly linked list ( give you ability to walk the graph in either direction ) --- good luck and have fun

Answer (score 0):

You could use Graphviz http://graphviz.org/
There also are Python bindings (here's an example https://github.com/rspivak/lsbasi/blob/master/part7/python/genptdot.py)